# Anchor tags in overlay jack-scroll approach

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement anchor points to scroll to certain "Views" on my Jack-Scrolling home page. I have used an approach shown on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KJupc/) or below. However, because of this approach any `<a name="xyz"></a>` tags in my code when referenced by `www.domain.com#xyz` just show the first "page" of my website. How can I work around this, or produce comparable results with an alternative tagging method?

```
<div id="projects">
    <section id="project-0" class="slide active"> Test 1</section>
    <section id="project-1" class="slide active"> testing 2</section>
    <section id="project-2" class="slide active"> This is testing 3</section>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var delta = 0;
var currentSlideIndex = 0;
var scrollThreshold = 30;
var slides = $(".slide");
var numSlides = slides.length;
function elementScroll (e) {
  console.log (Math.abs(delta));
    // --- Scrolling up ---
    if (e.originalEvent.detail < 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) { 
        delta--;
        if ( Math.abs(delta) >= scrollThreshold) {
        prevSlide();
        }
    }

    // --- Scrolling down ---
    else {
        delta++;
        if (delta >= scrollThreshold) {
            nextSlide();
        }
    }

    // Prevent page from scrolling
    return false;
}


function showSlide() {
    delta = 0; // reset
    slides.each(function(i, slide) {
        $(slide).toggleClass('active', (i >= currentSlideIndex));
    });
}

function prevSlide() {
    currentSlideIndex--;
    if (currentSlideIndex < 0) {
        currentSlideIndex = 0;
    }
    showSlide();
}

function nextSlide() {
    currentSlideIndex++;

    if (currentSlideIndex > numSlides) { 
        currentSlideIndex = numSlides;
    }
    showSlide();
}

$(window).on({
    'DOMMouseScroll mousewheel': elementScroll
});
```

Thanks very much, just to help you read the code, the approach is to place each of the slides on top of each other and then only show the one that is defined by the scroller index (which is incremented and decremented if the scroll is greater than our scroll threshold). - Possibly something using JQuery? Thanks for your help.